According to the Dharmasastras how many marriages are permissible for a Hindu man?
According to the Dharmasastras, how many marriages are permissible for a Hindu man? As far as I know, multiple marriages are permissible. However, is there an upper cap? Do Dharmasastras mention any specific upper limit?

As per Apastamba Dharma Sutra, only one wife is recommended.


If he has a wife who (is willing and able) to perform (her share of) the religious duties and who bears sons, he shall not take a second.

If a wife is deficient in one of these two (qualities), he shall take another, (but) before he kindles the fires (of the Agnihotra).


[ADS Prasna II, Patala 5, Khanda 11]


Oh! This is nice. I thought males could go on marrying as many as they want! Now, I understand, that they can remarry only in special cases, where the wife is barren. Makes sense. Thank you.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay I think only Kshatriyas that too kings were allowed to have multiple wives because of political things.
